# Login Checklist?

Tags: user-interface, authentication

Does anyone know of a login checklist online that goes through the overall requirements? Currently, we have the following overview of steps:

- Login Page
- Registration Page
- Thank you for creating account page (needs to be page instead of pop-up so that we can track this in Act-on)
- Registration email to user
- Registration email to client
- Login confirmation page for client to approve user in one click
- Login approved email to user
- Login declined email to user
- Forgot password page
- Forgot password emailed to user
- New password page (from email)

If you know of anything more thorough, or can see anything that may be missing (or is overkill), please let me know. Should I be posting this on Stack Exchange?

Comment: looks like you have covered all of the grounds (with the exception of stating the scope of files you are protecting via login)

Comment: Great point - this area is process, so I'm glad to hear we have all other bases narrowed down so far :)